# Error updating RVM

Tags: ruby, rvm

While updating RVM, i got this error:

```
bash: /contrib/ps1_functions: No such file or directory
```

Couldn't find any similar question. Does any one know how to solve it?
Thanks

Comment: Can you add the whole output when you run the install? Basically just copy and paste the terminal output including the command you use to install RVM.

Comment: So, the update was successful, but now every time i open a new terminal this error message appears before the prompt

Comment: Do you have something like `source "$HOME/.rvm/contrib/ps1_functions"` on your `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, or `.profile`? Search for `ps1_functions` on those files and show me how it looks like.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I had this code in my .bash_profile, but this peace of code was in the wrong line.
 Now it works perfectly!

Comment: Cool :) Can you explain what's wrong ([answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer))? That will help others who stumbled on the same problem with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem this way:

My .bash_profile was like this:

```
PS1="\$(~/.rvm/bin/rvm-prompt) $PS1" && source "$rvm_path/contrib/ps1_functions" && ps1_set
export PATH="/Users/name/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

and pasted the last line into the first:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
PS1="\$(~/.rvm/bin/rvm-prompt) $PS1" && source "$rvm_path/contrib/ps1_functions" && ps1_set
export PATH="/Users/name/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```